# How to open a .pbproj on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, osx-lion

I downloaded a sample code from the MAC OSX developer library and the code is the format of a .pbproj (Project builder) and im unable to open it on xcode.

I have tried the following without any luck:-

1) Rename FancyAbout.pbproj to Old.xcodeproj

2) Open Old.xcodeproj. Xcode will ask you to upgrade it.  Save it as
   FancyAbout.xcodeproj.

3) When the project opens, choose Project > Upgrade All Targets in
  Project to Native... to upgrade to the Xcode build system

4) Build and run.

I run a Mac 10.7.3 with Xcode on 4.3.2

Anyone have any suggestions on how i can get this running in xcode?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused, at the beginning of this your say, "without any luck" then you go through the steps and end with "it works." So does it work or not?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but i just copied that off some other question. Simply putting it, it does not work!

Comment: Can you post the link to that question.

Comment: Here it is
http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Nov/msg00310.html

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge older Project Builder, and even older Xcode projects can not be opened or upgraded directly. The only real way you could upgrade would be to find a previous version of Xcode that is able to open and upgrade the older project then save the project using the older Xcode and see if the newest Xcode is then able to open the upgraded project.

Or, simply create a new Xcode project and copy over all the source files from the old project into your new project and go from there. This option is probably considerably easier then trying to find older versions of Xcode to do the upgrade with.